# Select uri of oldest photo

Tags: mysql

Hello I have mysql tables `object` and `photo` with relation (1:N), one object can have multiple photos.

Photo object has column

> id, object_id, uploaded_at, uri

I need to create a SELECT to select object_id and uri of the oldest photo.
So for following data set:
[image: | id | object_id | uploaded_at | uri | | ---| ----------| -------------------- | ------| | 1 | obj_a | 2022-03-30 10:00:00 | uri_1 | | 2 | obj_b | 2022-04-01 10:00:00 | uri_2 | | 3 | obj_c | 2022-08-18 11:25:40 | uri_3 | | 4 | obj_a | 2022-08-08 16:55:26 | uri_4 | | 5 | obj_a | 2022-08-03 08:55:25 | uri_5 | | 6 | obj_b | 2022-07-18 13:57:45 | uri_6 |]

[image: | object_id | uri | | ----------| -------- | | obj_a | uri_1 | | obj_b | uri_2 | | obj_c | uri_3 |]

Can it be done in 1 query without subqueries?
I was able to achieve desired result with following query:

```
select object_id, uri from photo ph where uploaded_at = (SELECT min(uploaded_at) from photo inph where inph.object_id = ph.object_id) group by object_id, uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be done in 1 query without subqueries?

Use of sub-query is appropriate in your case and I think, you don't need to go for any other alternative to achieve the same result. Just in case, you want to see how it can be done without subquery.

```
SELECT 
    ANY_VALUE(object_id) AS object_id,
    ANY_VALUE(MIN(uploaded_at)) AS uploaded_at,
    ANY_VALUE(uri) AS uri
FROM
    photo
GROUP BY object_id;
```

For ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value